# Change external annotations location in IDEA 2019.3+

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations, external-annotations

IntelliJ IDEA lets you add external annotations.

[image]

However, the files go straight into the project's root directory.

[image]

How do I change the folder?
I can't find a setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is extremely confusing, and took me a long IDEA debug session to understand.
Let's say we start with a clean situation, and we add an external Annotation to a method of a **library**.

[image]

A popup appears, letting us choose the external Annotations root directory.

[image]

And we choose `untitled3`, the project's root directory. But ops, we made a mistake!
Now how can we change this directory? Where is it stored?
Well, actually not under any `$projectRoot$/.idea/*` XML file...

Let's debug IDEA. The "call" hierarchy is:

```
> AnnotateIntentionAction
  > AddAnnotationPsiFix#invoke
    > ExternalAnnotationsManagerImpl#annotateExternally
```

The last method `annotateExternally` calls `AnnotationOrderRootType.getFiles(entry)`, where `entry` is a `LibraryOrderEntry`.

[image]

Here `orderEntry.getRootFiles(getInstance())` gets called and the resulting `VirtualFile`(s) are used as library's external Annotations roots.

Where are they stored?

```
> Project structure
  > Modules
    > *your main module with dependencies*
      > *your library*
        > DOUBLE LEFT CLICK
```

[image]

Now press `CANC` over the *Annotations* entry, and you're done... Finally.
You can restart over.

Answer (score 0):

You may drag'n'drop the *annotations.xml* file in the *Project pane* and move it to the desired location or change the path explicitly in *Project Structure | Project Settings | Modules -> module Paths | External Annotations*

Comment: No problem hahaha. Maybe can you guys add some info for libraries on the External Annotations help page? I doubt I'm alone in this.

Comment: Hmm I've tried to reproduce the same annotations positioning with sample gradle project and haven't managed to reproduce the case without explicit adding of gradle lib + annotations.xml path. Can you please describe how have you defined the following path location?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hw4fXvl3hQkosjVs39TFXzHvpZWrnOsa
It's pretty simple. I defined two folders (`annotation-root-one`/`annotation-root-two`) as External Annotations paths in Project settings. Now, the first time you will add an external annotation to the `JSONObject#optJSONObject` method it will ask you where to put it, choose the root `untitled3`. That position will now be under the library settings as I showed in the answer (last image). The External Annotations paths are not used for libraries, only for local sources. But maybe I misunderstood and you meant something else?

Comment: Thanks for the sample and clarification. I got what you mean now, the case of annotating the external library will be added to the documentation.